# Report if one value is null don't show other value

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, rdlc, rdl

I'm trying to build a report with asp.net report.

If you check this image:

[image]

I'm showing a table with tickets and charge. The charge column has these value:

```
=Fields!Charge.Value
```

What I want to achieve is only to show the charge value if the ticket value is not null. So as you see in the image, there are 4 tickets visible and I want to show the charge only for those four tickets not all the charges.

Any idea how we can achieve that?

Comment: Can you modify the underlying SQL to exclude the rows you don't want? This would be the most efficient option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like the following in the charge column

```
 =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Ticket.Value), "", Fields!Charge.Value)
```

It should have worked otherwise you can try Fields!Ticket.Value == "" or Fields!Ticket.Value.ToString() == ""

Comment: will that hide the row completely or only show empty column for charge as well? Thx for help

Comment: To hide the row you can set the hide property using an expression- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159830(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: This solution also can be used with charts.